# Converting form lowercase to uppercase?

Tags: java

How can I convert a string from a lowercase to uppercase with all possible outputs?

For example, I have the string `'abc'`; it must give all possible outputs in uppercase to show this set of strings as output:

```
'abC','aBc,'aBC','Abc'ABc','AbC','ABC'
```

Comment: i considered   the orginal string as binary cod '000' 0 mean that is lower and 1 mean that is upper now using if statements for each time check if the last bit is 0 change it to 1 then go to next digits and so on .

Comment: That's a good start.  Post your code, and describe what's going wrong.  That will also help you think about the problem.

Comment: share the code... the boolean concept u have implemented...

Comment: the code is like @amit modi post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the algorithm to do this:

```
 String input = "abc";
 int length = input.length();
 for (int i = 1;i < 2^input.length();i++){
     String bitString = convert value of i into bits (eg, 1 = 001 , 2 = 010)
     //Iterate through length of bitString
     StringBuffer newString = "";
     for (int j = 1;j < bitString.length();j++){
        if(bitString.charAt(j)=='1'){
           newString.append(convertToUpperCase(input.charAt(j));
        }else{
           newString.append(input.charAt(j));
        }
     }
     print newString
 }
```

Comment: Note, `2^input.length()` won't do what you expect in Java.  `^` is the exclusive-or operator, not a power operator.  Try `1<<input.length()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Convert your `String` to an arrays `String.toArray()` and loop through it!
I think it's homework, so I won't give you the complete answer.

Have a look at the links: [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28java.util.Locale%29) and [`String.toUpperCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29).